# How to make a container occupy remaining vertical space inside fixed parent element?

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

I have some content at the top of a *fixed* (it has to be positioned relative to the viewport) `div` and a (scrollable) list below.

I want the list to start at the bottom of the sibling elements, and end at the bottom of the fixed parent element. I could use `top: 123px;`, but the top content is of variable height (same for `height:calc(100%-123px);` and `margin`).
There is something in every position that makes them unsuitable for this job (eg: `absolute` elements do not take siblings into account).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/komfhjdj/) (borders and margins aren't needed)

```css
#fixed-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 32px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 5px;
  right: calc(30%-5px);
}
#fixed-wrapper .scrollable-list {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.some-bar, .some-other-bar {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 2px;
  padding 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed-wrapper">
  <div class="some-bar">some variable length text</div>
  <div class="some-other-bar">some image or text</div>
  <div class="scrollable-list">
    <div class="list-item">item1</div>
    <div class="list-item">item2</div>
    <div class="list-item">item1</div>
    <div class="list-item">item2</div>
    <div class="list-item">item1</div>
    <div class="list-item">item2</div>
    <div class="list-item">item1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I make this design work? Or, alternatively, how could I possibly reorganize the DOM (or use other tags, ugly tables maybe) to have these properties?

Edit: the solution only needs to work under Chrome.

Comment: Just to clarify, so you want the list items start at the bottom of the red bordered box, don't you?

Comment: no, by the sibling elements i meant the siblings of the list, so the _green_ ones above

Comment: I got you, side notes, copy/paste the code from fiddle and insert it into the question itself, otherwise it may get closed.

Comment: Ahh...then yes, flexbox would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS3 flexbox. I added `<div class="scrollable-wrapper">` to make it possible for the layout you are trying to achieve.

See the comments inside the code snippet, it's quite easy to understand. So `flex: 1;` means `flex-grow: 1;` to take all space available.

https://jsfiddle.net/komfhjdj/1/

```css
#fixed-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 32px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 5px;
  right: calc(30%-5px);
  display: flex; /*added*/
  flex-direction: column; /*added*/
}
.scrollable-wrapper {
  position: relative; /*added*/
  flex: 1; /*added*/
}
.scrollable-list {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0; /*updated*/
  bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.some-bar, .some-other-bar {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 2px;
  padding 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed-wrapper">
  <div class="some-bar">some variable length text</div>
  <div class="some-other-bar">some image or text</div>
  <div class="scrollable-wrapper"> <!-- added this div -->
    <div class="scrollable-list">
      <div class="list-item">item1</div>
      <div class="list-item">item2</div>
      <div class="list-item">item1</div>
      <div class="list-item">item2</div>
      <div class="list-item">item1</div>
      <div class="list-item">item2</div>
      <div class="list-item">item1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, somehow I had no idea about the css3 solution..
Is the wrapper necessary or good by the way? `flex: 1` on the list also did it.

Comment: Wait, you mean this? https://jsfiddle.net/komfhjdj/4/ it scrolls but the width of the box becomes full, anyway feel free to play around, and find the best way that works for you.

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly this. So I also forgot to mention that the list is already full width (and intended to be). In the fiddle, the `position: absolute` was just my last attempt to fix this..
And I also got the answer now (some situation, where the wrapper actually helps).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using javascript like this: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/komfhjdj/3/

```
<div id="fixed-wrapper">
  <div id="varHeight" class="some-bar">some variable length text</div>
  <div id="staticHeight" class="some-other-bar">some image or text</div>
  <div class="scrollable-list" id="list">
    <div class="list-item">item1</div>
    <div class="list-item">item2</div>
    <div class="list-item">item1</div>
    <div class="list-item">item2</div>
    <div class="list-item">item1</div>
    <div class="list-item">item2</div>
    <div class="list-item">item1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var sHeight = document.getElementById('staticHeight').offsetHeight;
var vHeight = document.getElementById('varHeight').offsetHeight;
var totalHeight = sHeight + vHeight;

totalHeight = totalHeight + 6;

document.getElementById("list").style.top = totalHeight + "px";

</script>
```

Comment: I accepted the flexbox answer because I looked for a css solution primarily, but this also works for me. I can also listen for changes if I'm not mistaken?